# Running processes: "perl /tmp/dd" - what is this?

Tags: perl, webmin, exploit, virtualmin

I have a LAMP server with about 50 virtual domains, and am using Webmin/Virtualmin to manage the server.

When looking at running processes (`top`) I see one domain's username is running a couple of perl processes, and `ps` gives me the full command line:  `perl /tmp/dd`.  Note that this domain is a wordpress installation.

There is no `dd` file in the /tmp directory, so I can't tell what it's doing.  These processes have been running for about 3 days.  I can't kill them with standard `kill [pid]`, but must use `kill -9`.

Is this an exploit, or is it most likely part of webmin/virtualmin's maintenance scripts?

Comment: That's pretty much malware.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you give me any details?  It's running under one of the site usernames, so it doesn't have free reign of the system. Just sending out spam apparently.  Can you describe this malware?  I'm assuming its attack vector was a wordpress vulnerability, but they were running the latest version.

Comment: Nothing more than you've already given us. It's your server, after all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton never mind. I thought it might be a signature for a specific attack.